# $npm run server error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cmd, npm

when i attempt to boot a server for a web application i keep getting a error.

All i am doing is typing "npm run server" in terminal from the root of the folder and i get a error stating

> ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server . -p 3000
>
> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

then a whole load of NPM ERR!; if they are important please let me know and i will post them on here.

I do not have a load of experience when it comes to programming so keep the technical terms to a minimal please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the server.js file (or whatever the main file is) you are attempting to run?

Comment: what is "." doing? remove it !!!

Comment: thats the problem... there is no "." that i know of... all im doing is typing "npm run server" and that is the error i get

Comment: there is no problem with the file im working with.. im sure of it

Comment: can you add the package.json file?

Comment: please post your server.js file

Answer (score 2):

I HAVE FOUND THE ANSWER.

The problem was with the package.json file

before = "server": "./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server . -p 3000"

After = "server": "**node** ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server . -p 3000"

basically "**node**" was missing in the line

thanks Patrick Motard and everyone else who tried to help

Comment: so since i basically said that in the line ` node bin/http-server` of my answer, does that mean i get the points for having the correct answer? :)

Comment: Cool, do you know how to upvote and mark an answer as the solution?

Comment: Most of the time, it is a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I think the command you're trying to run is:

```
npm run serve
```

Not:

```
npm run server
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all.. I can't think of a circumstance where you would be calling a node_module lib file directly.. That said, what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

```
./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server . -p 3000
```

Is not what the instructions in the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) describe. You're trying to run it as if it's a script, but it's not. Your two options are:

Either install the module globally and run it against a js file.

```
npm install http-server -g
http-server [path] [options]
```

or install it locally and run it from the bin directory.

```
mkdir myapp
cd myapp/
jitsu install http-server
```

If you do not have jitsu installed you can install it via npm install jitsu -g

```
 node bin/http-server
```

Comment: i dont know why that is happening.. all i am doing is typing 'npm run server' from the root of the folder im working in and that is the error i get

Comment: i followed your instruction and im still getting the same error

Comment: What error are you getting. It's not the same error you got running it with ". -p 3000". Please make an edit to your post explaining what steps you are using and what the outcome is.

Comment: "attempt to boot a server " is not an explanation. :(

Comment: yhh sorry but all i am doing is typing "npm run server" in my terminal an nothing else

Comment: Thats not what i'm asking for. I want to know from start to finish what you're doing. What does your package.json look like. It should include npm commands in it that are running when you type 'npm run server'. I want to know how you installed your dependencies. And i want to see what your server.js file looks like.

Comment: You can't just say "i ran this command and this error popped up, why?" without including any information whatsoever. I don't know what code you're running. Don't know what library you're using. Nothing.

Comment: do i upload the files to online and send you he link to download ?

Comment: no. copy paste them into your answer and use the 'code' modifier to modifier to make it look like code.

Comment: sorry im new to this but ive found the answer